# du --zip myFile.zip?

Tags: zip, tar, du

What's the easiest way to use the "du" command on zip files? I'm sure this is quite a common use case, but I couldn't find anything using Google.

I'd rather not resort to mounting the zip file and running du as if it was an exploded directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard of `du` working for zip files, probably you should use `gunzip` for that purpose - http://www.abeel.be/content/determine-uncompressed-size-gzip-file

I think you should better ask on http://superuser.com

Command for listing  .zip archive is:

```
gunzip -l file.zip
```

For other formats I'll quote nice example from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/list-the-contents-of-a-tar-or-targz-file/):

> Task: List the contents of a tar file
>
> Use the following command: `$ tar -tvf file.tar`
>
> Task: List the contents of a tar.gz file
>
> Use the following command: `$ tar -ztvf file.tar.gz`
>
> Task: List the contents of a tar.bz2 file
>
> Use the following command: `$ tar -jtvf file.tar.bz2`

Comment: Thanks David. It seems like each unzipping program has its own listing mechanism which can display the size at the beginning of the line (gunzip and unzip do, I can't see anything for tar without more experimenting). It would be nice if there was a command that makes it easy, like the title of this thread.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat Wait a minute, so you have tar inside your zip then? Nevertheless I'll update answer with some links and example to make it simpler, but you should really consider reading `man gunzip`

Comment: No I don't have a tar inside a zip. What I meant is that the output of unzip -l and gunzip -l begins with the file size (like du) but tar does not, so you can't sort by size. Though the sort command can get around this. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/show-biggest-files-in-tar-archive-368486/ . Your answer has enough information to make it work. Thanks.